# jq: how to customize the atomize function for a large streaming use-case?

Tags: json, streaming, jq

I have a very large file with the following structure:

```
{ 
  "users": { ... },
  ...
  "stats": {
    "daily": {
      "k1": { ... },
      "k2": { ... },
      ...
      "kN": { ... }
    },
    "monthly": {
      "p1": { ... },
      "p2": { ... },
      ...
      "pN": { ... }
    }
  }
}
```

There are only two keys in `stats`: `daily` and `monthly`, which both contain a very large amount of key-value pairs.

I would like to stream all the key-value pairs inside of `.stats.daily` and `.stats.monthly` separately.
If the file was small, I'd simply do `jq '.stats.daily' myfile.json` and `jq '.stats.monthly' myfile.json`

I cannot figure out how to edit the `atomize` function from the cookbook in order to do what I want. Here's what I'm trying which doesn't work:

```
jq -nc --stream '
  def atomize(s):
    fromstream(foreach s as $in ( {previous:null, emit: null};
      if ($in | length == 2) and ($in|.[0][0]) != .previous and .previous != null
      then {emit: [[.previous]], previous: $in|.[0][0]}
      else { previous: ($in|.[0][0]), emit: null}
      end;
      (.emit // empty), $in) ) ;
  atomize(2|truncate_stream(inputs | select(.[0][0] == "daily"))
```

Can someone please explain how it works and how to fix it for my use-case? Thank you

Comment: See [How to create a Minimal, **Complete**, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you've indicated you want to handle the "daily" values separately from the "monthly" values, let's focus on the former.

For this, let's start by using just `fromstream` and `truncate_stream`:

With input like the example given, but adjusted so that it's valid JSON:

```
fromstream( 1|truncate_stream(1|truncate_stream(
  inputs | select( .[0][0] == "stats" and .[0][1] == "daily" ) )) )
```

would produce:

```
{"k1":{"a":[1]},"k2":{"a":[1]},"kN":{"a":[1]}}
```

If you have jq 1.6 then the above jq filter can be streamlined to:

```
fromstream(2|truncate_stream(
  inputs | select( .[0][0:2] == ["stats","daily"] ) ))
```

Now we have only to use `atomize` instead of `fromstream` to obtain the desired result.  For example, using jq 1.6, we see that:

```
atomize(2|truncate_stream(
  inputs | select( .[0][0:2] == ["stats","daily"] ) ))
```

would produce:

```
{"k1":{"a":[1]}}
{"k2":{"a":[1]}}
{"kN":{"a":[1]}}
```

### Invocation

```
jq -n -c --stream -f program.jq input.json
```

### An efficiency enhancement

On the assumption that objects in the input do not have repeated keys, the above solution can be streamlined so that once the key of interest has been processed, no further processing is done.  This can be achieved using `run/3` as defined below.  The streaming solution then becomes:

```
atomize( 1 | truncate_stream( 1 | truncate_stream(
  run( inputs; .[0][0:2]; ["stats", "daily"] ))))
```

Or with jq 1.6:

```
atomize( 2 | truncate_stream(
  run( inputs; .[0][0:2]; ["stats", "daily"] )))
```

#### `run/3`

```
# emit the first run of items in the stream for which f == $value
def run(stream; f; $value):
  label $done
  | foreach stream as $x ( {};
      ($x | f) as $k
      | if .start then (if $k == $value then . else .stop = true end)
        elif $k == $value then .start = true
        else .
        end;
      if .stop then break $done 
      elif .start then $x
      else empty
      end );
```

Comment: wow, thanks for such a detailed and quick answer. Keys are indeed unique. It is really hard for me to understand your `run` function though. There is something I still don't understand though: could you please point me to an explanation of the [0][0:2] syntax?

Comment: .[m:n] accesses the array elements from .[m] to [.n-1] inclusive.  See the jq manual .  `run/3` does not require any knowledge of the `--stream` option, but it does require some understanding of `foreach` and streams. You might find this "Stream-Oriented Introduction to jq" helpful:  https://github.com/pkoppstein/jq/wiki/A-Stream-oriented-Introduction-to-jq See also https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/FAQ

Comment: Thanks, pkoppstein's intro looks great. The jq FAQ is too elliptic for me.

Comment: As I understand it, this code will check each of the streaming output (starting with `[["users", ...], leaf]` and so one. If the first-level keys (such as `users` in my example) are very big subtrees, is there a way to make it faster by not scanning all the streaming output from these and jumping directly to `stats`?

Comment: No, that's one of the limitations of the --stream option and why it's usually only used when all else fails.

Answer (score 0):

The jq streaming parser (activated by the --stream command-line option) handles very large JSON inputs economically but can be quite tricky to use even for relatively simple tasks, so the command-line utilities [jm and jm.py](https://www.github.com/pkoppstein/jm) (the former based on "JSON Machine" and the latter using a streaming Python parser) may be of interest.

Here at any rate are some very simple solutions for the present task using these utilities:

```
< $IN jm.py -s -i stats
{"daily": {"k1": {"etc": "..."}, "k2": {"etc": "..."}, "etc": "...", "kN": {"etc": "..."}}}
{"monthly": {"p1": {"etc": "..."}, "p2": {"etc": "..."}, "etc": "...", "pN": {"etc": "..."}}}
```

```
< $IN jm.py -i stats --values
{"k1": {"etc": "..."}, "k2": {"etc": "..."}, "etc": "...", "kN": {"etc": "..."}}
{"p1": {"etc": "..."}, "p2": {"etc": "..."}, "etc": "...", "pN": {"etc": "..."}}
```

```
< $IN jm -s --pointer /stats
{"daily": {"k1":{"etc":"..."},"k2":{"etc":"..."},"etc":"...","kN":{"etc":"..."}}}
{"monthly": {"p1":{"etc":"..."},"p2":{"etc":"..."},"etc":"...","pN":{"etc":"..."}}}
```

```
< $IN jm --pointer /stats
{"k1":{"etc":"..."},"k2":{"etc":"..."},"etc":"...","kN":{"etc":"..."}}
{"p1":{"etc":"..."},"p2":{"etc":"..."},"etc":"...","pN":{"etc":"..."}}
```

Note that both jm and jm.py are designed to handle very large JSON inputs.

Disclaimer: I wrote both the jm and jm.py scripts but they are just wrappers around JSON Machine and ijson respectively.